# Is it okay to modify Android's system files? (for device company)

Tags: android

I work for a company which is making device using the Android platform.

A UI designer asked me if it is possible to modify not just apps UI but whole Android's basic UI for example, status bar color, setting menu's font and so on.

I found a way to do this (editing `services.jar`... right?) but I wonder if it is okay to do it (release a device with modified Android framework code... does Google allow this or not).

Does anybody know about this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder is it okay to do it

So long as you are not allowing third-party apps on the device, you can do whatever you want. Android is (mostly) under the Apache License 2.0.

If you want to allow third-party applications on the device -- particularly via the Android Market -- you need to think about compatibility. Making UI changes that break third-party applications will make your device very unpopular.

Comment: Specifically, if you want the google co-branding as a google experience device (to be able to ship the Android Market and other google apps on it) you are going to have to pass google's compatibility tests, some of which are basically programmatically enforced  "rules"

Answer (score 0):

Android is open source. You can do whatever you want